# Coefficients for Laurent series expansion are unique

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$$ for all $1<|z|<2$. Show that the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ are unique.

I want to use the fact that the Laurent series of any function $f$ is unique. But to use that, I have to know that $f$ is holomorphic in $1<|z|<2$. So how can I do it then?

Comment: Here is the proof from a different approach: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205385/prove-laurent-series-expansion-is-unique?lq=1

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Suppose there's another expansion
$$f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n.$$
But then we would have
$$0=f(z)-f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n-\sum_{-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (a_n-b_n) z^n.$$
But for this to be true $\forall z$ in the domain, we must have $a_n-b_n=0, \forall n$. So, the coefficients, are unique.

Comment: But what are you using to conclude that $a_n-b_n=0\forall n$?

Comment: The fact that $g(z)\equiv 0$ is analytic and its series expansion has all $c_n=0$.

Comment: Hi @MateusSampaio, what do you mean by $g(z)$? I didn't see the function $g$ defined.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree the function defined as $g(z)=0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Mateus Sampaio But how do you know that g(z)=0 has a unique Laurent expansion? Maybe there's an expansion of g(z) where some terms are not zero.