# Prove Laurent Series Expansion is Unique

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $A=\{r<|z|<R\}$, where $0\le r<R\le \infty$. Suppose that there are two series of complex numbers $(a_n)_{n\in{\mathbb Z}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ such that $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^n$ for $z\in A$. Show that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. This means that the Laurent series expansion is unique.

Hint: It suffices to show that if $f\equiv 0$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$. Use $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} -a_n z^n$ to construct a bounded entire function.

---

Hi everyone, I've set out to prove that the Laurent series expansion of a function is unique. I found a *very* short and nice proof of uniqueness [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575028/coefficients-for-expansion-is-unique), however my problem's hint goes a different direction. Is there any reason not to favor the simple proof I linked to?

I'd like to figure out what to do with the hint given and what bounded entire function to construct. Once I find a bounded entire function, I have a feeling I will need to cite Liouville's Theorem to help me somehow, which says every bounded entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ is constant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems to me, at least, that the hint is in the same direction. This is the punchline of the other proof.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(z)=\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{-1}{a_{n}}{z^n}+\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{-n}}{z^n}+\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

Define $g(z)$ as

\begin{align}
g(z)&=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n, \forall z, |z|\leqslant R. 
\\
&=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{-n}}{z^n}, \forall z, |z|>R
\end{align}

Clearly $g(z)$ is bounded and analytic on both $|z|\leqslant R$ and $|z|>R$. So is bounded on entire domain.

Since $\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^n=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{-n}}{z^n}$ for $|z|=R$, $g(z)$ is analytic on entire domain through analytic continuation. Thus $g(z)$ is bounded entire function, and $g(z)=c$, or $a_n=0$ for all $n$ except $n=0$.

Then if $f(z)\equiv 0$, $a_n=0,$ for all $n$, which means Laurent Series is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the previous answer intends to define $g(X)$ as 
$$
g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n
$$
for $|z|<R_2$ and
$$g(x)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{-n}}{z^n}$$
for $|z|>R_1$, where $0<R_1<R_2$.
Then we have $g(x)$ is analytic in $\mathbb S^2$ and thus is a constant. Hence, $a_n=0$ for $\forall n\in\mathbb Z$.